# How to parse comma delimited integers from a string in c++

Tags: c++

I have a function recieving a string, which is a pair of comma delimited integers in a fashion such as "12,4".  How can I parse the integers out of this string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string)

Comment: In php you would use the `explode` function and use the comma as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends whether or not you can depend on the incoming data being valid. If you can, I'd do:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

std::pair<int, int> split(std::string const& str)
{
    int const a = std::atoi(str.c_str());
    int const b = std::atoi(str.c_str() + str.find(',') + 1);
    return std::make_pair(a, b);
}
```

Comment: @rubenvb : I'm not clear what you mean by that. `atoi` is a C API and consequently cannot throw exceptions.

Comment: ok, bad wording. What I meant was that when it chokes it produces nonsense: `atoi` on a non-integer gives 0, just like `atoi` on 0 gives 0. And if the input needs validation, you might as well use the type-safe `stringstream` alternative.

Comment: @rubenvb : Which is why I specifically said "If you can (depend on the incoming data being valid)". If the data needs validation, I agree with you that `atoi` is completely inappropriate.

Comment: agreed, but it's still an awful function to use in C++. For example, see the discussion resulting from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017001/like-atoi-but-to-float/5017022#5017022

Comment: @rubenvb : Possibly, but given that I explicitly called out the caveat with using it, I don't think a downvote is warranted. Personally, I use boost.spirit.qi for this sort of thing, but I hate using it for answering trivial questions like this because it tends to raise more questions than it answers.

Answer (score 2):

`std::getline` implements the basic "split" functionality (I don't see it mentioned in the first few answers at the other question.)

```
vector< int > numbers;

istringstream all_numbers_iss( "12,4" );
string number_str;
int number;

while ( getline( all_numbers_iss, number_str, ',' ) // separate at comma
        && istringstream( number_str ) >> number ) {
    numbers.push_back( number );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the extraction from the `istringstream` fail for passing a const as a reference for the lhs?

Comment: @wilhelm: No, because it is a member function.

Comment: It's not a `const` member. [27.6.1.2.2]

Comment: @wilhelm: It doesn't matter; the rvalue isn't converted to a reference.

Answer (score 1):

if you use Qt, you can use `QString::split();`

Answer (score 0):

boost tokenizer works pretty well. Click [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm) for example.